# Facebook login response object

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app that uses the facebook login service, I get the response object containing the user id, is this user id unique? and is it permanent? if the user changes his name would it affect the user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User id is returned from facebook sdk is unique and permanent. And name change has no effect on user id. hopfully it helps you